# saving all excel sheets as pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that stores all the dataframes from a given excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
xl=pd.ExcelFile('pandas_worksheets.xlsx')

mydic={}
for i in xl.sheet_names:
    mydic[i] = xl.parse(i)
```

I can call any dataframe sheet using this syntax:

```
mydic['olympic']
```

But how do I simply call "olympic" to return that dataframe? (without using mydic)

somthing like this works...

```
olympic = xl.parse('olympic')
```

But the same logic does not work in the for loop

```
for i in xl.sheet_names:
    i = xl.parse(i)
```

It saves the last dataframe as literal i instead of replacing it with sheet-name.

---

update:

```
mydic={'a':1, 'b': 2}

for i in mydic:
    i = mydic[i]

a

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

(expected value 1 instead of NameError)

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? It looks like you want to dynamically generate variables, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's frowned upon injecting and polluting the global name space when you can maintain a dictionary, you can still do it in a few ways:

With `globals()`

```
mydic={'a':1, 'b': 2}

globals().update(mydic)
print a
print b
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

---

With `exec()`:

```
mydic={'a':1, 'b': 2}

for i in mydic:
    exec("%s = mydic['%s']"%(i,i))

print a
print b
```

Output:

```
1
2
```